# Range mapping in Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, range-map

**MAPPER DATAFRAME**

```
 col_data = {'p0_tsize_qbin_':[1, 2, 3, 4, 5] ,
           'p0_tsize_min':[0.0, 7.0499999999999545, 16.149999999999977, 32.65000000000009, 76.79999999999973] ,
           'p0_tsize_max':[7.0, 16.100000000000023, 32.64999999999998, 76.75, 6759.850000000006]}
map_df = pd.DataFrame(col_data, columns = ['p0_tsize_qbin_', 'p0_tsize_min','p0_tsize_max'])
map_df
```

[image: Mapper]

in Above data frame is `map_df` where column 2 and column 3 is the range and column1 is mapper value to the new data frame .

**MAIN DATAFRAME**

```
    raw_data = {
        'id': ['1', '2', '2', '3', '3','1', '2', '2', '3', '3','1', '2', '2', '3', '3'],
        'val' : [3, 56, 78, 11, 5000,37, 756, 78, 49, 21,9, 4, 14, 75, 31,]}
df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['id', 'val','p0_tsize_qbin_mapped'])
df
```

**EXPECTED OUTPUT MARKED IN BLUE**

[image]

look for `val` of df dataframe  in map_df min(column1) and max(columns2) where ever it lies get the  p0_tsize_qbin_ value.

For Example : from df data frame val = 3 , lies in the range of `p0_tsize_min`  `p0_tsize_max` where `p0_tsize_qbin_` ==1 . so 1 will return

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `pd.cut()`

```
bins = map_df['p0_tsize_min'].tolist() + [map_df['p0_tsize_max'].max()]
labels = map_df['p0_tsize_qbin_'].tolist()
df.assign(p0_tsize_qbin_mapped = pd.cut(df['val'],bins = bins,labels = labels))
```

or

```
bins = pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(map_df['p0_tsize_min'],map_df['p0_tsize_max'])
map_df.loc[bins.get_indexer(df['val'].tolist()),'p0_tsize_qbin_'].to_numpy()
```

or:

```
pd.Series(map_df['p0_tsize_qbin_'].tolist(),index = pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(map_df['p0_tsize_min'],map_df['p0_tsize_max'])).reindex(df['val']).tolist()
```

Output:

```
   id   val p0_tsize_qbin_mapped
0   1     3                    1
1   2    56                    4
2   2    78                    5
3   3    11                    2
4   3  5000                    5
5   1    37                    4
6   2   756                    5
7   2    78                    5
8   3    49                    4
9   3    21                    3
10  1     9                    2
11  2     4                    1
12  2    14                    2
13  3    75                    4
14  3    31                    3
```